# php artisan make:migration AppServiceProvider not found LARAVEL 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I'm new to Laravel 5 and I'm trying to do

```
php artisan make:migration create_projects_and_tasks_tables --create="projects"
```

and I got this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'dodong\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found
```

anyone has ideas what's wrong with this one? any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Edit app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php as below:

```
<?php namespace dodong\Providers;
```

Comment: Could you also explain?

Comment: When you change app name with: artisan app:name, it did not change app name in  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to search your project for `'dodong\Providers\AppServiceProvider'`? It's not a standard Laravel service provider; maybe you removed a composer package but forgot to update the providers list in `config/app.php`?

Another alternative is that it's misspelled since the first letter in "dodong" is not capitalized, and Googling it renders no relevant results.